# What is power for?

Tags: neverwinter

There is an attibute called power and the description says that increase the damage and heal powers but I don't understand how much. Every weapon has a damage, so, Should I understand that this attribute is added to the weapon base damage or the power only affect to some kind of skills?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power increases the damage and healing done by your character

You can see its impact by hovering your cursor over the power stat in your character sheet (the "C" key).

For instance, mine says "Contributes to: Damage and Healing Bonus  +167.5"

Also, look at the powers tab within your character sheet.  That shows the actual damage/healing ranges for a given power using your current equipment/skills.  If you slot a weapon with more or less power you can gauge the impact it has on your powers.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see your answer until right now

Comment: @lemon Can you elaborate, simply? Say, you're hitting for 100 damage. Then say you increase your power by 100 (maybe with a potion). Now how much damage should you be doing?